# Android Layout for XLarge devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have layout, layout-xlarge, values values-xlarge folder. I assigned dimemension for normal layout and for xlarge layout through dimens.xml file.

In preview windows it looks ok, but when I run application on emulator dimension for xlarge layout seems to be same size as for normal layout.

Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your emulator must belong to the normal screens category. These are the details of the various categories according to the size of the screens.

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

More details here :
**[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)**